# Embedding Partials as data in Mustache

Tags: php, mustache

I'm running into a problem with mustache templating and I hope someone can help. Specifically, if I embed a partial as a data item within my template, Mustache doesn't completely parse my template. **How do I get Mustache to completely parse all of the template, including partials as data?**

```
<?php
$m = new Mustache;

$template = '
    {{header}}
    {{body}}
    {{footer}}
';

$data = array(
    'header' => 'header', 
    'body' => '{{> embedded}}', 
    'footer' => 'footer'
);

$partials = array(
    'embedded' => 'embedded'
);

die($m->render($template, $data, $partials));
?>
```

What I expect to see is:

```
header embedded footer
```

but what actually happens is

```
header {{> embedded}} footer
```

If I put `{{> embedded}}` directly into the template it works, however for one reason or another, I can't hardcode that value right now. I also can't use a php specific solution as the template needs to function equally well on client side with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mustache is "completely parsing" your templates. It's just not double-parsing them. In fact, Mustache takes specific pains *not* to double-parse your templates. Doing that would create an opportunity for mustache injection (like SQL injection, but for your templates). This is a Bad Thing :)

It's possible to accomplish what you're looking for with higher-order sections, but that would require some code. That said, it shouldn't be too tough to write both a PHP and JavaScript implementation.

Comment: heh, I doubt I'm going to get a more authoritative answer than that... Can you elaborate on mustache injection and how it would happen? As I understand, Mustache recursively parses through partials, so how is that different from what I tried above? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This way will do. What do you think?

```
    $partials = array(
        'embedded' => 'embedded'
    );

    $m = new Mustache_Engine(array('partials' => $partials));

    $template = '
        {{header}}
        {{>embedded}}
        {{footer}}
    ';

    $data = array(
        'header' => 'header', 
        'footer' => 'footer'
    );

    die($m->render($template, $data, $partials));
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include why/how your answer solves the problem.